# Trigonometric equation with high exponents

Tags: trigonometry

Solve the following equation:
\begin{align}
\sin^{14}x+\cos^{14}x=\frac{169}{64}\cos^{6}2x
\end{align}

I tried setting $\cos^2x=a$ such that the equation would become $a^7+(1-a)^7=\frac{169}{64}(2a-1)^6$ and then expaned both sides, but the obtained polynomial isn't pretty at all...

Comment: Maybe you can use $x^{14}+y^{14}=(x^2)^7+(y^2)^7=(x^2+y^2)((x^2)^6+(x^2)^5(y^2)+...+(x^2)(y^2)^5+(y^2)^6)$. Inside the long expression, you can group terms such that you get $(x^2+y^2)=1$ terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  2\sin^2 x &= 1-\cos 2x \\
  2\cos^2 x &= 1+\cos 2x \\
  128(\sin^{14} x+\cos^{14} x) &= (1-\cos 2x)^7+(1+\cos 2x)^7 \\
  &= 2(1+21\cos^2 2x+35\cos^4 2x+7\cos^6 2x) \\
  169\cos^6 2x &= 1+21\cos^2 2x+35\cos^4 2x+7\cos^6 2x \\
  0 &= 162\cos^6 2x-35\cos^4 2x-21\cos^2 2x-1 \\
  0 &= (2\cos^2 2x-1)(81\cos^4 2x+23\cos^2 2x+1) \\
  \cos^2 2x &= \frac{1}{2} \quad \text{or} \quad
  \frac{-23\pm \sqrt{23^2-4(81)}}{2(81)} < 0
\end{align*}

Can you proceed?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!